# Playing online poker with Italians (on PokerStars)?

Tags: poker-tools

Does anyone here know if and how can I play on Pokerstars with a friend of mine from Italy? I cannot find him when he's at a table and he can't find me either.

We don't even have the same table names in the list.

Something's fishy!

Thanks!

Note: I'm from Romania.

Answer (score 5):

Pokerstars.it or players in Italy are authorize per the Italian government license with PokerStars to play against players from the Italy only.  that's why you cannot find player

Answer (score 0):

Try starting a home club and give him the ID and the password. Be careful though, as all home clubs need to be approved based on a description you give when creating it. I doubt they'll approve something like this just so 2 players can play with each other.

Another thing you could do is register to a single-table SNG and give your friend the tournament ID. Tournaments can be searched via ID on PokerStars (Ctrl+T in the main lobby) so he can very quickly register. If you can do this within a few minutes (using IM there's no reason not to), then it'll work :) .